# Can a Flex Spark List have itemrenderers that are 100% width?

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, flex-spark

This is an odd one for me but I am also new to Spark. I have a List class with an itemrenderer. How can I get the itemrenderers to divide the List width between them? Normally, I would think this would be a easy as giving the renderers a percent width but that no worky. Any ideas?

Application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    minHeight="600"
    minWidth="955"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:ArrayCollection id="dta">
        <fx:Object 
                label="one" />
        <fx:Object 
                label="two" />
        <fx:Object 
                label="three" />
        <fx:Object 
                label="four" />
    </s:ArrayCollection>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List 
        width="100%"
        borderColor="red"
        dataProvider="{dta}"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        itemRenderer="ProgressIndicatorItemRenderer">

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="0" />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
</s:Application>
```

Itemrenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer 
    width="100%"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    autoDrawBackground="false"
    showsCaret="false">

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="selected" />
    <s:State name="done" />
</s:states>

<s:Rect id="progressIndicatorBackground"
        left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor 
                color.done="0xCCCCCC"
                color.normal="0xCCCCCC"
                color.selected="0xF6A139"
                alpha="1" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<s:Label 
        width="100%"
        text="{data.label}" />

 </s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "divide the List width between them"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are just missing some properties on the layout itself:

```
<s:List width="100%" useVirtualLayout="false" borderColor="red" dataProvider="{ dta }"
    itemRenderer="ProgressIndicatorItemRenderer">

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="0" requestedColumnCount="-1" requestedMinColumnCount="-1" variableColumnWidth="true" />
    </s:layout>

</s:List>
```

Setting the variableColumnWidth to true and useVirtualLayout to false should resolve your problem. RequestedColumnCount and requestedMinColumnCount are set to -1 by default but it's good to set them explicitly :)

I hope the code above helps.

Comment: Man, thank you! That was driving me nuts. I really think there is a bug in there somewhere though.

Comment: The spark List has useVirtualLayout set to true by default.  Virtual layouts do not respect layout elements' major axis percent size property (percent width in HorizontalLayout).  To get this to work you will need to set useVirtualLayout to false as MonkeyCoder suggests.  See the Spark Virtualization spec for more details: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Spark+Virtualization